# jekyll: check request country

Tags: localization, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I saw there was some plugins that are handling "localization" like:

- https://github.com/prometheus-ev/jekyll-localization
- https://github.com/Anthony-Gaudino/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin
- https://github.com/incompl/jekyll-localize

But the are mostly for translating purposes and for which I assume they are only checking the `Accept-Language` or `lang` headers on the requests.

I have a jekyll site where I want to offer price depending on the location of the user. Is there a plugin or a way to do that right now with jekyll? Or what's the suggestion for this problem (external service maybe)?